# Open file in a specific split in vim (with fzf)

Tags: vim, vim-fzf

I often use a common layout on the screen - a few vertical splits, file tree (NerdTree) on the left.

When I need a new buffer, I typically want it to go into a specific split. For example, imagine the following window structure:

`| file_tree | split1 | split2 |`

Now I invoke the file listing command (in my case, fzf). When I find the file name, I'd like to press something like `Ctrl+1` to open the file in `split1`, `Ctrl+2` to open the file in `split2`, etc. How can I implement such shortcuts? Specifically, with fzf, if possible.

Otherwise, the experience is a little awkward:

- I can always open a new vsplit, but then I need to close some of the other ones (because now 
  there's too many), they get reshuffled, etc.
- I can first focus a specific split, and then invoke the file listing command. That works, but I keep forgetting about this, and half of the time I keep opening the file in the tiny `file_tree` split.

Comment: Are you using vim or neovim? Fzf from the box supports the following shortcuts for opening found file: **Ctrl+V** - opens a file in new vertical split, **Ctrl+X** - opens a file in new horizontal split, **Ctrl+T** opens a fine in a new tab.

Comment: Neovim. Yes, I know all shortcuts that fzf provides, but I was looking for how to open a file in a specific split, not in a new split.

Comment: So you are searching your file with fzf? Then your active buffer will be the target as `dajnz` says. If you don't remember the name, well: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/ says it all. the default file browser works better with splits than nerdtree and [vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) may add some sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening a file in a specific split looks not possible, unfortunately. This is because of splits nature, it is sort of dynamic viewport for a buffer that can be rearranged inside a window at any moment (with shortcuts like **Ctrl+W, Shift+H/J/K/L**), created and deleted. Also if you have an unsaved buffer in a split, Vim won't allow you to open a new file there without saving the existing one, and in this case, the approach you would like to use won't work too.

You can always switch quickly to a certain split with a shortcut **N, Ctrl+WW** where N is your split number. And you can navigate between adjacent splits using shortcut **Ctrl+W, h/j/k/l**.

This is how I work with splits: I usually have 6 splits open (2 rows and 3 columns), and NerdTree I open with my shortcut only I need it. To open a file in some split I navigate there with a shortcut **N, Ctrl+WW**, where N is split number and then I open a file using NerdTree (if I can't remember a file name), or Fzf (when I know file name).

Maybe you'll find it more convenient for you to use tabs, in this case, you can open each new file in a new tab with **Ctrl+T** shortcut after selecting it in Fzf. And then you can switch between tabs using **gt** (forward) and **gT** (backward) shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting this was the case. Maybe I can actually use a combination of window navigations to achieve what I need. For example, to open a file in a left vertical split - open new split to the right, swap with split to the left, move left and delete split. Etc.

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple files and open all the selected files each in it's own tab? Because currently if I select multiple files and press CTRL+t it will open all the selected files in the same tab.